# Uniform continuity and limit

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, uniform-continuity

This is related to my [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/850732/uniform-continuity-and-translation-invariance). Consider the function $a(s)=\dfrac{1}{1+s^2}$. Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $t\mapsto a(t)f(t)$ is bounded uniformly continuous.

How can we show that 
$$\sup_{s\in \mathbb{R}}|a(s)f(s+t)-a(s)f(s)|\to 0,$$
when $t\to0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's similar to what I did yestersay.

Let $t\in \mathbb R$

**Claim 1**: The function $\displaystyle x\to \frac{a(x)}{a(x+t)}-1$ is bounded by $\displaystyle \frac{\sqrt{t^2+4}+t}{\sqrt{t^2+4}-t}-1$

**Claim 2**: The function $af$ is bounded by some $M>0$

---

Let $\epsilon >0$

By uniform continuity of $af$, there is some $\alpha >0$ such that $\displaystyle |x-y|\leq \alpha \implies |a(x)f(x)-a(y)f(y)|\leq \frac{\epsilon}2$

Since the function $t\to \frac{\sqrt{t^2+4}+t}{\sqrt{t^2+4}-t}-1$ goes to $0$ as $t\to 0$, there is some $\beta >0$ such that $\displaystyle |t|\leq \beta \implies \forall s\in \mathbb R, \left|\frac{a(s)}{a(s+t)}-1\right| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2M}$

Let $\delta := \min(\alpha,\beta)$

---

Let $s\in \mathbb R$ and $t$ such that $|t|\leq \delta$

$\displaystyle |a(s)f(s+t)-a(s)f(s)| \leq \left|\frac{a(s)}{a(s+t)}-1\right||a(s+t)f(s+t)| + |a(s+t)f(s+t)-a(s)f(s)|$

$\displaystyle\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2M}\cdot M + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$

$\leq \epsilon$

This is valid for all $s$.

Taking $\sup$ yields $\displaystyle \sup_{s\in \mathbb R} |a(s)f(s+t)-a(s)f(s)| \leq \epsilon$

---

It has been proved that

$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta >0, |t|\leq \delta \implies \sup_{s\in \mathbb R} |a(s)f(s+t)-a(s)f(s)| \leq \epsilon$

Comment: Thank you, the key point was that $\sup_s|\dfrac{a(s)}{a(s+t)}-1|\to0$, Mathematica is useful to do such maximizations.

Comment: @user50618 may I ask for some context about your questions ?

Comment: Yes of course, it is just to prove the strong continuity on $0$ of the operator of translations: $A_tf=f_t$ defined on the space $X$ I mentioned on the other question. That is I want to show that for all $f\in X$ we have $|A_tf-f|\to 0$ when $t\to 0$. The space $X$ is equipped with the norm $|f|=\sup_s |a(s)f(s)|$. The other question is just to make sure $A_t$ maps $X$ into itself.